# Swift 3 UITapGestureRecognizer not receiving tap

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a gesture recognizer to one of my views to detect taps,
here is my code:

```
class DateTimeContainer: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onTap))
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func onTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        openDatePicker()
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view?.tag != self.datePickerTag && !self.isDatePickerOpen() {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

When I tap on my view the code enters into the `gestureRecognizer shouldReceive` method and enters the condition for which it returns true.

But the `onTap` method is never called, can someone tell me why?

**EDIT**

Adding `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` I managed to get it working.
But it had a strange behaviour: it was like it received the tap only in the main view and not in subviews.
So to make it simple I solved by adding a button inside my view and by using:

```
self.button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTap), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: what are you tapping on to call your `onTap` method?

Comment: on the whole view

Comment: You're missing the parameter part in the selector.

Answer (score 5):

You may have forgotten to do this:

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Also, typically the UIViewController subclass is usually the target and contains the method used for the tap gesture.

You don't need to set a delegate for a tap gesture (usually)

Comment: I need the delegate to discriminate when to handle the tap to perform an action or not

Answer (score 1):

You can You Gesture

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action:#selector(self.handleTap(recognizer:)))
userImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    recognizer.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
userImage.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

And method call selector

```
func handleTap(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

           // do your coding here on method 



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing the codes

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onTap))
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

inside `init` block not in `awakeFromNib()`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are adding your gesture on a UIView. As such, at that `ViewController` where you have added this ContainerView, inside the `viewDidLoad` method, add this line of code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.YourContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourCurrentViewController.openDatePicker())))
    self.YourContainerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Note. Do not forget to add `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true.